# Python: How to serialize with json when entity keys are introduced

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I have been dumping my json effectively until I started doing one-to-many relationships in GAE as you can see with `Employees` below. I've tried json dumping with the code as seen in json handler below but I'm getting a `ValueError: Circular reference detected` error. When I debug, I see a number of my dates being printed out till it hits that new entry object I have just stored that now has employees with a key reference. Tried a number of variations from similar SO solutions but all not working for me.

**model.py**

```
class Project(ndb.Model):
    projectID = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    startAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True)
    endAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    employees = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Employees', repeated=True)

class Employees(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    role = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**handlers.py**

```
def post(self):
r = json.loads(self.request.body)
print str(r)
employee_keys = []
for emp in r['Employees']:
    employee = Employees(name=emp['name'], role=emp['role'])
    employee.put()
    employee_keys.append(employee.key)


g = Project(projectID=int(r['ProjectID']),
            description=r['Description'],
            title=r['Title'],
            employees=employee_keys,
            startAt=datetime.strptime(r['StartAt'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p'),
            endAt=datetime.strptime(r['EndAt'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p'))

project_key = g.put()
project_key.get()
print project_key
```

**json handler**

```
class commentsJsonHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):  
        rec = Project.query()

        def date_handler(obj):
            print obj
            if isinstance(obj, datetime):
                return obj.isoformat()
            else:
                return obj

        self.response.out.write(json.dumps([dict(r.to_dict(), **dict(id=r.key.id())) for r in rec], default=date_handler))
```

Comment: Can I suggest  you focus on the code in you json.dumps call.  It's not very readable, so someone has to invest time reformatting and trying to work out what you are attempting to achieve,  May be try runing the iterator without the json.dumps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I already fixed this. I just replaced `return obj` with `return str(obj)`